# Problem using where with date in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba, date

I am trying to execute an SQL statement in a VBA script.  I have gotten the script to run, but it ignores the where with a date filter.

I have researched and tried every option I can find, but just cant seem to get it to work.

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("Select [adjustment_number], [status], [tax_adjusted],[amount], [gl_date],[creation_date],[apply_date],[comments],[type],[adjustment_type],[dbo].[Code_Combinations].[segment1], [dbo].[Code_Combinations].[segment10],[dbo].[Code_Combinations].[segment11],[dbo].[Code_Combinations].[segment12],[dbo].[Code_Combinations].[code_combination] FROM [dbo].[AR_ADJUSTMENTS_ALL] " & _
   "left outer join [dbo].[Code_Combinations]  on [dbo].[AR_ADJUSTMENTS_ALL].[CODE_COMBINATION_ID] = [dbo].[Code_Combinations].[CODE_COMBINATION_ID] where [gl_date] >= " & gldate & ";")
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Have you tried your query directly in that DBMS to see if it works there? What data type is the `gldate` column (how is it defined in the table)?

Comment: The gldate is probably calling ToString() and is getting put in the query. Yes f writing the query by hand, I would put single quotes around the date string. I would also enforce a sql friendly format like yyyy-MM-dd.  What you should really do is replace the string addition with a parameter (usually @p0 and pass the date in as a parameter.  The conn.Execute is smart enough to format the parameter for you.

Comment: SQL Server?  Put single quotes around your date in the `WHERE` clause.  `where [gl_date] >= '" & gldate & "';"`. Assumes that `gldate` is a valid date, and `[gl_date]` is of a date datatype.

Comment: OMG... DBro, the ' and ' around it worked.. Something as easy as that.. WOW.. I have spent hours.. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

(Copying this from my comment above, into an answer, since this solved your problem)

SQL Server? Put single quotes around your date in the `WHERE` clause.

```
where [gl_date] >= '" & gldate & "';"
```

Assumes that `gldate` is a valid date, and `[gl_date]` is of a date datatype.